# Get value in onSelect which is selected in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to catch another value from AJAX but it is giving me an error `Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function`.

Here is my code.

```
     source: function(name, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: af_vars.af_ajax_url,
        data: "action=get_listing_names&name=" + name,
        success: function(data) {
         // response(data);
            var tickers = [];
            $.map( data, function( item ) {
                for (var index = 0; index < item.length; index++) {
                    tickers.push(item[index]['tickers']);
                }
            });
            console.log(tickers);
            response(tickers);
        },
        error: function(response) {}
      });
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item) {
      //my code
    }
```

and here is my PHP ajax request code

```
$titles = array();
    if (!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $term) {
            $data = array();
            $data['tickers'] = get_term( $term->parent, 'exchange' )->name ? esc_attr( get_term( $term->parent, 'exchange' )->name ) .' : '. addslashes($term->name) : addslashes($term->name) ;
            $data['isArchived']= get_term_meta( $term->term_id , 'ticker_archived', true) == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
            $titles[] = $data;
        }
    }else {
        $titles[] = "No results found";        
    }      
    echo json_encode(array(
        'results' => $titles
        )
    );
```

So, I want to show tickers in dropdown and want isArchive result as hidden value to pass along with tickers in `onSelect`

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function" means "The variable E is not a string." .......Being that the variable "e" is used in the part that's written as "      //my code
", the most important part of your code isn't visible. Can you show us what's inside the "OnSelect" function?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way it is working for me. or if you can put it on server and give me access so i can check that there as well as.

```
source: function(query, process) {
    var objects = [];
    map = {};
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL+"/admin/getmember",
        data: 'q=' + query,            
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i, object) {
                map[object.membername] = object;
                objects.push(object.membername);
            });
            process(objects); 
        }
    }); 
},
updater: function(item) {
    $('#hiddenId').val(map[item].id);
    return item;
}
```

PHP code

```
$memberResults = array();
foreach($members as $k=>$member){
    $memberResults[$k]['id'] = $member->id;
    $memberResults[$k]['membername'] = $member->fname.' '.$member->lname;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could register to any change:

```
$('html').bind('input', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Other option is to get update on blur (leaving focus of element)

```
$("input").on('blur keyup change click', function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

"Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function" means "**The variable 'e' is not a string.**"

Beyond that.......Being that the variable "e" is used in the part that's written as " //my code ", you aren't sharing the most important part of your code (The part that contains an error isn't visible here).

Can you show us what's inside the "OnSelect" function? Perhaps give us a codepen?